# Rename [spacy-pytorch-transformers] to [spacy-transformers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Can we have [spacy-pytorch-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-pytorch-transformers) renamed to [spacy-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-transformers)?

This tag is in reference to the [spacy-transformers](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers) python packages that prior to Octover 2019 was named [spacy-pytorch-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-pytorch-transformers).

Update from the creators of SpaCy mentioning the rename: ["*Update (October 2019)
The spacy-transformers package was previously called spacy-pytorch-transformers. Since this blog post was published, Hugging Face have released an updated and renamed transformers package that now supports both PyTorch and TensorFlow 2. We have updated our library and this blog post accordingly.*"](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-transformers)

Comment: There's [more than meets the eye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ae-Pl-Q34ng) to this request...

Comment: If anyone wants to know, the youtube link above.. is not relevant to the request.

Comment: Joking apart, this request is straighforward and should be implemented immediately.